# Regla redirecciones con RewriteRule en .htacess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirección, rewriterule

Estoy intentando crear una regla para redirigir muchos links.
Básicamente lo que intento hacer es redireccionar esto:

- _https://dominio/producto-de-ejemplo-3-x-2-3.html

A esto:

- _https://dominio/producto-de-ejemplo-3-x-2_3.html

He intentado esto pero no ocurre nada.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1_$2.html
```

He intentado también con RedirectMatch 301, RedirectMatch y da error interno del servidor.
He probado añadir al final la bandera [R=301] y nada.
Mi problema no solo es la regla en si misma, sino que no consigo redirigir nada.
Lo he metido dentro de esto y nada.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

RewriteEngine On
.
.

</IfModule>
```

Lo único que me funciona es Redirect 301 poniendo una URL concreta, pero no me serviría ya que quiero hacer un redireccionamiento masivo.

He comprobado que el servidor es Apache y que el módulo del rewrite esta activo.
[image: Apache]

[image: Rewrite]

Respecto al htaccess no sé si puede haber algún problema, pero si me funciona esto `Redirect 301 /dirección.html https://direccionnueva.html` debería funcionar lo otro, no?
Paso el trozo de código del htaccess, por si acaso:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1$2_$3.html
```

También mencionar que estoy trabajando dentro de un subdominio, pero que yo sepa no tiene porque afectar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba con `RewriteRule ^(.*)([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1$2_$3.html` a ver si tienes más suerte

Comment: Creo que las dos reglas, la tuya y la mía, son correctas. Pero no logro que se redirija la página. He probado añadiendo flags por si acaso y nada. Debo estar olvidando algo. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Pruebalo primero harcodeando algo, tipo `RewriteRule ^indicemalo.html /index.html` y si eso no te funciona entonces es algo del servidor, del .htaccess o del modulo del rewrite que no estan bien implementados o quizas no estas corriendo ni apache en ese servidor

Comment: ¿Esto te funciona o no?  `RewriteRule ^dirección.html /direccionnueva.html`   Hasta que no consigas que esto te funcione olvídate de arreglar las otras rules más complejas. Ponla justo despues del `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: Me ha funcionado esto `RewriteRule ^/dirección.html /direccionnueva.html` Esto parece que también `RewriteRule ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ /direccionnueva.html`. Pero ahora intento esto `RewriteRule ([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).html$ /otradireccion.html` y apunta a /direccionnueva.html otra vez. Es más he quitado la regla y me sigue apuntando a /direccionnueva.html

Comment: Ok, solo necesitaba borrar la caché del navegador

Comment: Si, perdona, no encontraba esta conversación y no pude avisarte de ello... las peticiones 301 suelen dejarse en el cache de los navegadores a menos que sean voluntariamente exentas de ello (mediante el uso de dos headers de cache-control con los valores **no-cache** y **no-store**)